# How to draw a specific dimensions circle using ellipse tool in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes, tools

I am following a tutorial in which the author has asked to draw a `70px x 70px` circle using the ellipse tool, but i can't figure out how can I draw a circle with exact dimensions in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around, i found out this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or, draw an ellipse then alter the measurements in the control bar at the top of the screen.

[image]

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get to this in Photoshop CS5. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ryan it should be, but I don't have CS5 installed to test. CS5 had shape layers though... that is all that is required.

Answer (score 1):

Select the ellipse tool and double click it on the image. A pop-up will appear where you can enter the dimensions manually.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click the hand like icon shown in the red circle above. The ellipse option should come up.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! I edited your answer a little bit to improve your English. Let us know if you have any questions!