# How to create shapes with transparent areas inside in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a shape layer that is a circle, and I want to add a shape layer to the center of it, but for that shape to be transparent and you can see through both layers.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Before drawing the second shape, choose Subtract Front Shape from the shape option on the control bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :-

1) Add a texture or any design photo of your choice.

[image]

2) Select the ellipse tool

[image]

3) Draw the shape.

[image]

4) Select the custom shape tool.

[image]

5) Make sure you select the 'Subtract from shape are' option from the top menu.

[image]

6) Draw your desired shape.

[image]

Additional resources : [How to draw a specific dimensions circle using ellipse tool in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22077/how-to-draw-a-specific-dimensions-circle-using-ellipse-tool-in-photoshop/22097#22097)